# How to handle a Swift Package's dependent artifact checksum?

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager, xcode12

Using Xcode 12 beta and swift-tools-version 5.3, you can link to a framework, like this:

```
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "Stripe",
            url: "https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/releases/download/v19.3.0/Stripe.xcframework.zip",
            checksum: "fe459dd443beee5140018388fd6933e09b8787d5b473ec9c2234d75ff0d968bd"
        )
```

But when I needed to update the checksum (I had it wrong) I get

```
: artifact of binary target 'Stripe' has changed checksum; this is a potential security risk so the new artifact won't be downloaded
```

How can I reset this, or override it when I need to change the checksum?

Comment: Sorry, maybe i didn't understand. The checksum is only declared in the library, and updated whenever a new artifact is generated. So every new binary will have its own checksum stated on library's side, Package.swift. You should be able to update this checksum on Library's side.

Comment: I had to remove items related to "bitbucket.org" from macOS Keychain in order to eliminate checksum error. See details in my comment: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/2059#issuecomment-1144019427

Answer (score 15):

In order to get rid of the error, you need to purge Xcode's local package caches.

In Xcode's File menu, select 'Swift Packages' and then 'Reset Package Caches'