# Swift package manager checksum of binary target does not match

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I have a binary `.xcframework` swift package that lives on GitHub. Occasionally after users update the package to a new version Xcode starts spitting out this error when resolving the package graph.

```
checksum of downloaded artifact of binary target [...] does not match checksum specified by the manifest [...]
```

Why is this occurring? Is there something that's incorrectly configured in the package?

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64070049/1187415 ?

Comment: yeah unfortunately that answer doesn't work in this scenario, which is why I felt this warranted it's own question. Clearing the cache manually, as I answered, does however provide a workaround but it's temporary, eventually the cache will bug again.

Comment: I had to remove items related to "bitbucket.org" from macOS Keychain in order to eliminate checksum error. See details in my comment: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/2059#issuecomment-1144019427

Answer (score 5):

Clearing SPMs package cache is the only way I know how to mitigate this issue. The package caches lives at:

```
~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm/repositories
```

I usually opt to nuke this whole folder but you can target the specific package instead.

This however is only a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

I reset my Xcode Cache and it resolved the issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).